# Restart customtkinter using button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

this might be a noob question but I have a simple script to monitor the current in my area which I use customtkinter as my GUI.
The script have two buttons which are Start and Restart. The Start button is to start the program and the Restart in to simply to Restart the whole code again which you could see on the snippet of the code below.

```py
import sys
import os
#from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import customtkinter

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program."""
    root.destroy()
    os.startfile("testbed.py")

root = customtkinter.CTk()

#Label(root, text="Hello World!").pack()
#Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program).pack()

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Hello World!").pack()
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program).pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```

but when I clicked on the restart button it does not execute the `os.startfile("testbed.py")` part is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: `os.startfile()` will use *default program* to execute the given file.  So what *default program* you have set to execute a .py file?

Comment: Try changing `os.startfile("testbed.py")` to `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, __file__])` (of course you need to import `subprocess`).

Comment: ahaa I see, I tried changing it to `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, __file__])` and it works! Thank you! Didn't think to use subprocess instead